# slider with thumbnail having navigation & previous and next button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

Anyone please suggest a slider with carousel thumbnail navigation. Previous and next button for both thumbnail and slider. Googling i get sliders of this type, but both the thumbnail div and slider div are of same width. But i want sliders where slider div and thumbnail div of different width.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I feel your frustration in searching for these online.

Here are few that I have used before and work well.

- These use arrows as Next and Prev buttons

[MenuCoolusing Jquery](http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-3)

[Wow Slider Using Jquery](http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-thumbnail-slider/)

Wow Slider has a lot of demos on there to browse around

Comment: Thanks. Atlast, i found this "lofslidernews" jquery plugin that helped me to satisfy my need.